# How to put an img element behind a transparent img element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, transparent

I have two img elements and I want the first image.png to go behind the transparent image.png. I have tried a lot of different things (z-index, transparent background color, rgba background color, positioning absolute and relative, nesting one in a div, making them both divs). Right now i've been trying to use a transparent .png image. The image .png is actually behind it, but it still shows through it. Please help.

html:

```
<body>
    <main class="site-wrapper">
        <div class="carnival"></div>
        <div id="images">
            <img id="divbox" src="images/divbox.png">
            <img id="clown1" src="images/clown1.png">
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

js: (i did the styles in js b/c I was interested in learning how to do it that way):

```
//styles

//divbox:
document.getElementById('divbox').style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById('divbox').style.transform = "skew(-2deg)";
document.getElementById('divbox').style.marginTop = "21%";
document.getElementById('divbox').style.marginLeft = "47.6%";
document.getElementById('divbox').style.height = "200px";
document.getElementById('divbox').style.width = "200px";
document.getElementById('divbox').style.border = "1px solid orange";
document.getElementById('divbox').style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById('divbox').style.zIndex = "2";

//clown1:
document.getElementById('clown1').style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById('clown1').style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
document.getElementById('clown1').style.marginTop = "21%";
document.getElementById('clown1').style.marginLeft = "53%";
document.getElementById('clown1').style.border = "1px solid green";
document.getElementById('clown1').style.position = "relative";
document.getElementById('clown1').style.zIndex = "1";
```

Thanks for any help, please let me know if I can answer questions.

UPDATE:

Sorry for not being clearer. I have now achieved getting the image behind the other image, but since the image ontop is transparent, the image behind is showing. How do I stop this?

Here is an example of what is happening:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2mw9egx.jpg

Notice the orange border is ontop so it is definitely ontop.

**UPDATE 2**:

This should make it really clear what I want. Again sorry for the confusion:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/eamb0n.jpg

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please, please, please just use a stylesheet!

Comment: Curious to know how this is supposed to look.

Comment: Don't use #ids when you will probably have multiple of those as it seems or at least add classes so you will have css rules for all those clowns etc that have the class="clown"

Comment: When changing css through JS just use the one DOM query. `var divbox = document.getElementById('divbox').style` then `divbox.display =` etc :) Makes it easier to read and is easier on the browser.

Comment: @nepeo He shouldn't be using js at all but css for all those that don't change

Comment: So you want the lower portion of clown face that is inside the orange box to not show through?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: That means that you need another opaque div between clown and the one in front of it that will cover the lower part of clown's face. Right?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis yeah... but he did say he was just practicing the technique so thought I'd point him at the aliasing method

Comment: yeap :) It wasn't clear at first

Comment: That is what divbox is for. I want the clown head to disappear when it goes behind the divbox. the divbox image however, is transparent so the clown head doesn't disappear behind it. divbox needs to be transparent because the background image needs to be visable. I could just photoshop the exact portion of the background that divbox is positioned on and make that the image for divbox, but I would have thought an easier way is possible.

Comment: All you need to do is set a higher z-index on the object that is behind the clown head currently. If you make a JSFiddle using your assets, it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gdx48fu/. Might need to reload a couple times to see a good example of the overlay working.

Create a wrapper DIV for your two images. Set that wrapper DIV's to `position: relative` so we can use absolute positioning on one of the images it contains. By doing this we prevent the absolute positioned image from potentially aligning itself elsewhere in the page, like the upper left corner of the browser window.

Then, set the position of our overlay image, the transparent PNG, to `position: absolute` along with `top: 0` and `left: 0` to align it with the first images upper left corner.

You can do this without using `z-index` if you watch the order you include your images. Place the image you want behind the transparent PNG in the markup first followed by the transparent PNG.

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/">
    <img class="overlay" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city">
</div>
```

```css
.img-container {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.25; /* using this to replicate the transparent PNG */
}
```

**EDIT**

The OP's requirements have changed to include how to prevent an image behind a transparent image from showing through the transparent image.

Here is an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gdx48fu/2/.

This approach I wrapped the transparent PNG in a wrapper DIV and set it's background color. I used white in my example but you may use any color.

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/">
    <div class="overlay">
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.img-container {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    top: 15px; /* shifting overlay for illustrative purposes - not use case code */
    left: 15px; /* shifting overlay for illustrative purposes - not use case code */
}
.overlay img {
    opacity: 0.25; /* using this to replicate the transparent PNG */
}
```

Not perfect but I'm unsure of how else to proceed.

**EDIT 2**

It seems the OP wants to do a form of masking. You can do this with `overflow: hidden`.

I have updated the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gdx48fu/4/

In this updated answer I have kept the wrapper DIV and set it with a fixed width and height. Then applied `overflow: hidden`. What we are doing here is creating an invisible window that will only show content when it is within the dimensions of the window.

To have the image appear as if it is coming out of the base layer image simply adjust the position of the image inside the wrapper DIV. For the jsFiddle simply play with the value of `top` in `.mask img`.

This will need a little tweaking for the proper placement and size of the `.mask` DIV to fit your needs but hopefully points you in the right direction.

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/">
    <div class="mask">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/50/city">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.img-container {
    position: relative;
}
.mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red; /* for illustrative purposes */
}
.mask img {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be completely gone behind the transparent image, not just faded.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, but I updated my question, hope that helps. I actually wanted to to animate the clown head so it comes out from the side of the transparent div, so i need to to not show. I want it to look like its coming out from behind something in the actual background image. Really sorry for the confusion.

Comment: upvote just for using lorempixel.com that I didn't know :) Thanks!

Comment: I understand now. You are talking about a masking effect. I think I have an idea for that.

Comment: @MarkusHallcyon just tweaked it again to be more suitable for your use case.

Comment: Yes thanks so much, overflow: hidden is exactly what I needed. Sorry for the unclear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the css opacity property ?

```
#clown1{ opacity:0.3;}
```

Comment: Yeah that just makes the whole image faded.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to figure out what you're trying to achieve. If you don't want image1 visible behind image2 than just don't have image1 on the page ???

Comment: No because im going to animate it so it comes out from the side of the transparent div, so i need to to not show. I want it to look like its coming out from behind something in the actual background image.

Comment: Got ya, seen the edited post now..working on a solution

Answer (score 0):

1. make both images' position `absolute` instead of `relative`
2. for the above to work, some common ancestor (i.e. `#images`) must have a non-default position too (e.g. `relative`)
3. forget `zIndex` - all else being equal, the latter element will be "topmost"
4. put all the above in a CSS style sheet instead of in JS code!

Forgetting the other transformations and margins, etc, the core CSS that you need is:

```
#images {
    position: relative;
}

#divbox, #clown1 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I did all this, and the image is behind the transparent image, but since the transparent image is transparent it is showing through it. How do I stop that from happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarkusHallcyon so your question is not how to stack the two images properly? Are you asking how to make a transparent image not transparent? Please be more precise, possibly a simple visual example/mockup of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Put them both in a parent container. Make the parent have position: relative and put both images having position:absolute. That way they will stack.(Something like that that I didn't check The order of img's could be wrong - play around a bit.

CSS:

```
.parent > img.transparent {
    position: absolute;
}
.parent > img {
    position: absolute; opacity: 0.5
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent" style="position:relative">
    <img src="other.png" class="transparent"/>
    <img src="transparent.gif"/>
</div>
```

Some more explanation: When you make a parent/ancestor element's position relative it means that its contents that are absolute will be relative to the parent and not to the whole window

Comment: From memory, I think you've got the elements the wrong way around - the transparent one needs to be uppermost, and therefore last.

Comment: I did all this and it just fades the image. The image is actually behind the other, the real problem is that the other image is transparent so it shows up through it, but I dont want it to when it's behind it.

Comment: you mean you need dynamic opacity when it is in front of it? 
If that is the case then you should be changing opacity/visibility with javascript - or you want the image to be behind the transparent but not show through? I don't get what you want to do.. if that is the case it doesn't need to be behind it at all but hidden/display:none